# Can we create dynamodb transaction ConditionCheck expression for complex attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Want to check if I can use ddb ConditionCheck feature for this case.

Let's say I have two tables `Account` and `Credential` both having primaryKey as `customerId`. Credential table has an attribute called `payload` which is a complex json structure. `payload` has an field called email which is reachable at `paylaod.a.b.email`.

Can I perform an update operation on `Account` table for primaryKey K1 with the condition that perform operation only if  `paylaod.a.b.email` equals abc for key K1 in Credential table?

Could not find such complex conditional checks are supported or not.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html#transaction-apis-txwriteitems

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html

Comment: Did you try a `TransactWriteItems` with a second `ConditionCheck` on the email?

Comment: Hi, The conditionExpression passed for ddb transaction expect a string to be passed. Ref: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTransactionWriteExpression.html#withConditionExpression-java.lang.String-) . I could not find how to pass such complex conditionExpression as string. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-example.html

Comment: `ConditionCheck` is what you’re looking for. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html